# Any closed set of R is compact?

Tags: real-analysis

I found a question which has asked to prove or disprove any closed set of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact.

**My Attempt**

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a set of itself and it is closed ($\mathbb{R}$ is open and closed too. So I though I can get it as closed one here) it is closed. That means any closed set of $\mathbb{R}$ is closed. But the problem is that Any set of $\mathbb{R}$ is not bounded since $\mathbb{R}$ itself is not bounded. So I think that statement is false.

**Problem**

But I don't know whether my proof is true or false. If someone can please help me to figure this out.

Note : Problem has clearly stated that "Any set of $\mathbb{R}$"

Comment: You're right, you have produced a counterexample. $\mathbb R$ is not compact, yet it is a closed subset of itself. Similarly, $\mathbb Z$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ which is not compact.

Comment: $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}(-n,n)$. This is a cover of open sets, but a finite subcover does not exist. So $\mathbb R$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The Heine-Borel Theorem states that a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. So, you a specific counter-example you just need to exhibit a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is closed and unbounded. For instance $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks. I know that $\mathbb{R}$ is both open and closed. So can I get it as either as Open or as closed whenever I want?

Comment: Yes. So you may also used the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact as your counter-example.